# Is it possible to enter the shopping area at terminal 2E at Charles de Gaulle, if I land at terminal 1, upon arrival?

Tags: paris, shopping, cdg

I am traveling to Paris from Norway, landing at terminal 1 at Charles des Gaulle airport. I want to purchase a chanelbag during my trip, and there is a chanel boutique at terminal 2E, hall K. My question is if it is possible to enter terminal 2E, after I have landed at terminal 1. Will I be able to go through security to enter terminal 2E, considering my final destination is Paris, and I dont have any connecting flights? I would like to purchase the bag upon arrival because then I may have a chance of finding the bag I'm looking after in the Paris boutiques, if I dont find it at Charles de Gaulle.

Answer (score 2):

The area you describe is used for flights to non-Schengen countries, and [you must exit French passport control to go there](http://cdgfacile.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/plan-t2e.pdf), so I do not believe you'll be allowed to go there unless you have a flight departing from that terminal.